# What is the equivalent capacitance in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, capacitance

[image: schematic diagram]

I was trying to find the equivalent resistance here, but I do not know how to deal with the empty wire. Do we just simply ignore it? What happens to the charges, current and to the last capacitor in detail?

Comment: the "empty wire" is a short, shorting out the right most capacitor. redraw it and then ask yourself what is the total capacitance.

Comment: Suppose there is stream of water flowing into a closed floodgate (or through narrow path). But now you carve a very wide open channel around the flood gate (or narrow path). Does the flood gate or narrow path still make a difference as far as the water is concerned? Are they still effectively there doing anything?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMujMX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The reason this is the equivalent circuit is that the ideal battery has infinite capacitance, zero ESR in series while in parallel with two ideal caps resulting in 3uF that is nothing by comparison.

This lame circuit emulator is too big, but I hope you don't over-react.

Comment: "This lame circuit emulator is too big" - ISTR there is an option to reduce it?

Comment: it appears to be auto resize to fit width , so I added a dummy part to right

Comment: some resizing suggestions here:- https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/smaller-circuitlab-schematics?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes I use the dummy line  or a dot of white text off to the side when I dislike the scale, unless I wanted to make an obscenely simple point